# Submit form inside iframe when click button outside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a `form` with an `iframe` inside, this `iframe` contains another `form`. 
This is the `html` skeleton :

```
<html>
    <form>

        <iframe src="..." id="form_iframe">
            //in this form I have another form with id = test_frame_id and name
        </iframe>

        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="save"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

So how can I submit two forms whan I clik on `submit_button` ?
I tried in jQuery `$("#test_frame_id").submit()` but it's doesn't work

Comment: Try trigger click http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ to simulate a button press on the submit button of your iframe when you click the button outside the iframe.

Comment: is it the iframe hosted on the same domain, if so use javascript: `myIframe.contentDocument.querySelector('form').submit();`